# How to increase scala stack size?

Tags: scala, stack, size

I am getting a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`, when I execute a Scala program.

I believe that the stack size can be set with `-DXss=n`, but it does not work
on my system:

```
  Scala compiler version 2.7.7final and
  Linux 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu
```

The attached program witnesses the problem on my system.

```
// scalac StackOverflow.scala
// scala StackOverflow 6000
// scala -DXms=200M -DXmx=200M -DXss=200M StackOverflow 6000

object StackOverflow {
  def recur(k: Double): Double = {
    // check effects of various commands
    println(k)
    // try to prevent tail recursion
    if (k>0) return recur(k-1)+k/(k+1)
    else return 0.0
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (args.length == 0) println("Missing argument");
    val k = args(0).toInt+0.1
    recur(k)
  }
}
```

Sergio

Comment: You can also rewrite your function to be tail-recursive and check that the compiler compiles it as a loop with the `@tailrec` annotation.

Comment: @Jean-Philippe: `@tailrec` is only available since 2.8.
@Sergio: **Please** update to a recent version (2.9.0.1 currently), Scala got giant improvements between 2.7 and 2.9.

Answer (score 12):

I think what you want is `scala -J-Xss200m`

Comment: I ran into a StackOverflowException in Scala IDE while compiling. This solved my problem: I configured under Window -> Preferences -> Scala ->Compiler->Advanced, Additional command line parameters: -J-Xss256m

Comment: In addition to the comment above, the same configuration needs to be added to eclipse.ini as well, as described [here](http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/faq/index.html#I_am_running_out_of_stack_space_in_Eclipse___How_do_I_increase_the_stack_size_). Make sure to set it at -Xss256m.