# increase scala stack size during maven build

Tags: scala, maven, stack-size

While compiling a scala project using maven (mvn compile) , I am getting error: java.lang.StackOverflowError.
I got the same from eclipse as well, but could solve it by giving Additional command line parameters: -J-Xss256m  for scala compiler , as given here [How to increase scala stack size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591452/how-to-increase-scala-stack-size)

But I am getting the same error while doing "mvn compile". How can I solve this ? Basically how to increase scala stack size while building via maven

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure the scala-maven-plugin in the `pom.xml` like bellow

```
<project>
  ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <jvmArgs>
            <jvmArg>-Xms256m</jvmArg>
            <jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
          </jvmArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
  ...
</project>
```

For more see http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/example_compile.html